# I want to convert a video link to an m3u8 file

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, m3u8

I want to convert a **video link** to an **m3u8** file That means I can give a video for the input of the link and I can watch the same video with the extension **m3u8** for the output.

**Please help me with this.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ffpmeg and ffprobe for video converting / procesing.

try this library [PHP-FFmpeg-video-streaming](https://github.com/aminyazdanpanah/PHP-FFmpeg-video-streaming)